# Seaborn barplot n smallest/largest values

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
index | counts
A     |   10
B     |    1
C     |    9
```

The `counts` column is unsorted. How can I plot only `n_smallest` and `n_largest` values based on `counts` only? I can use `df.nlargest()` and `df.nsmallest()`, but I wonder if there is any more pythonic way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order`:

```
df1=pd.Series(['a','a','0','a','b','b'])
sns.countplot(df1,order=['a','b','0'])
```